# Unable to "Finish Editing" in Experience Manager

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I'm having trouble with a new Experience Manager setup, I've got the page and component templates configured and am able to enter Experience Manager, insert a piece of content onto the page and the preview updates correctly.

However, when I click "Finish Editing" on the ribbon bar to save my changes, I get a error notification at the top, and a red exclamation mark appears on the content border for the page.

The error notification contains the following message and details:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
 at Tridion.UGC.DataExtenders.ComponentAndPageExtender.ProcessRequestItem(XmlTextReader reader, String uri)
 at Tridion.UGC.DataExtenders.ComponentAndPageExtender.ProcessRequest(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
 at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ProcessRequest>b__0(DataExtender extender)
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
 at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessRequest(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
 at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessRequest(XmlTextReader input, Object[] methodParameterValues)
 at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.General.SaveItem(String id, String xml, Boolean doneEditing)
 at SyncInvokeSaveItem(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

And the message shown in the red exclamation mark popup is:

> **Invalid Content in "page name"**
>
> You cannot save this Page because it contains invalid content.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Thanks

**UPDATES**

Page Name is "Layout E", not sure what difference that makes though?

Comment: What's the page name?

Answer (score 10):

The error might be a red herring in this case, as the stack trace is from the UGC Data Extender.

You may have a problem with UGC - perhaps missing configuration or an incomplete installation. Check the UGC log or the Event Viewer for more details on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

If (like me) you installed the HR1 on top of the SP1 prior to add the UGC feature, then you have overwritten the hotfix 79283 when you enabled UGC.

To fix the issue, just manually replace the Tridion.UGC.DataExtender.dll from a working Tridion box (with HR1 installed) to the following folder: [Your_Tridion_install_path]\web\WebUI\Webroot\bin.

Back up the DLL before you replace it and restart Tridion.

This solved my issue, hope the same for you.